# MATLAB uitable created by GUIDE to update data sets

Tags: matlab, uitableview, user-interface, dynamic

I'm currently working on a GUI that has a uitable within it. The idea is to allow the user to input a string and press a button to add a new row of cells, like so: [ui_table_currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTk1O.png).

In addition to this, when the user clicks 'accept', the data set so far would be saved. This means if the user were to load up the GUI again, the same data set would be shown as when they closed down the GUI.

In practice, I've managed to save the data set with the users input into the workspace in MATLAB, however, I cannot update the data set that is shown in the uitable when I reload the GUI, unless I use GUIDE and change uitable via (Inspector > Table Property Editor > Data > Change data value to the selected workspace variable).

My question is this: How do I get uitable to retain the data set it has when I close it, without manually having to change it through GUIDE?

Comment: You can save the data to a file and read the file every time the gui starts

Comment: Didn't you try anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two files created with GUIDE.  For the sake of example, let's say your's are named raimo.fig and raimo.m.  Let's also say you gave your uitable the tag, 'table_1'.

If you edit the raimo.m file, you should see a line like this

```
% --- Executes just before analysis is made visible.
function raimo_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)`
```

Load your data from the file within this function, and then give it to your user data.

Here's a made up example of how to do it:

```
a = load('yourAmbiguousData');
set(handles.table_1,'table',a);
```

I don't know how your data is saved, or what is called, but if you have pulled it out of your uitable correctly, you can just put it back in there with a set command.